# Why does Array.push not work on arrays with Vuelidatevalidations?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I have multiple formArrays inside a form variable. On adding vuelidate validations to these formArrays/collections, Array.push doesn't work properly.

FormArray and Form Data

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        experience: [{
          employerName: '',
          department: '',
          from: null,
          to: null,
          tillDate: false,
          type: null,
          noOfYears: null,
          noOfMonths: null,
          other: null,
        }],
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: null,
        course: null,
```

Vuelidate validation rules

```
  validations: {
    form: {
      experience: {
        $each: {
          type: {
            requiredIf: requiredIf(function() {
              return this.openExperience;
            }),
          },
          other: {
            requiredIf: requiredIf((obj) => obj.type === 'Other'),
          },
          noOfMonths: {
            minValue: minValue(0),
            maxValue: maxValue(11),
          },
          noOfYears: {
            minValue: minValue(0),
          },
        },
      },
      name: {
        required,
      },
      email: {
        email,
      },
      phone:{
        numeric
      },
      dateOfBirth: {
        maxValue(val){
          return this.$dateFns.sub(new Date(),{years: 18}) > new Date(val);
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

Function to add formArray

```
    addExperience(){
      this.form.experience.push({
        employerName: '',
        department: '',
        from: null,
        to: null,
        tillDate: false,
        type: null,
        noOfYears: null,
        noOfMonths: null,
        other: null,
      });
      const length = 'experience' + (this.form.experience.length-2).toString();
      document.getElementById(length).scrollIntoView();
    },
```

I tried removing the vuelidate rules and it worked as expected. [Screen Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I8-AtALnG3_z2EXflBBFBJ7PAUNZ3HMn/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

I had a computed property named 'open'. In the getter for the property, I clear the entire form for a specific condition. It turns out that adding another formGroup (Array.push) to the formArray would end up invoking all the computed properties, and in turn, calling the getter for 'open' and clearing the form.

I ended up moving the code block in the computed property getter to the mounted life-cycle hook and it works fine now.